# How to iterate through objects and display in rows using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this response from the my backend service with the help of following code.

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      status: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axio.get("http://localhost:8083/monitors").then(res => {
      this.setState({
        status: res.data
      });
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <br /><br />
        {/* ok {`ok ${this.state.status}`} */}

        {Object.entries(this.state.status).map(([key, value]) => {

          console.log('key name = ', key);

          value.map(el => {
            console.log(el.name + " - " + el.overall_state);
          })
        })}

      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

The `console.log(el.name + " - " + el.overall_state);` produces the below output:

```
Service one - OK
Service two - PENDING
Service Three - OK
.
.
.
.
Service 100 - OK
```

Like wise there are multiple services.

I am using `bootstrap` and I want to show them in cards (card title is `name` and the description is `overall_state`

**But more importantly I need to show `4` cards per row**

So I how can I implement this with `bootstrap` `row` feature?

```
<div className="container">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-3">
              // show card with `name` and `overall_state` value
            </div>

            <div className="col-3">
              // show card with `name` and `overall_state` value
            </div>

            <div className="col-3">
              // show card with `name` and `overall_state` value
            </div>

            <div className="col-3">
              // show card with `name` and `overall_state` value
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

So it would look like below image (this is just how it should looks like, `4` cards per row until every service is shown)

PS: Don't mind the title and description of the below image

[image]

This is the JSON reponse I am getting from `res.data`

```
[{'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': [], 'deleted': None, 'query': '"ntp.in_sync".over("*").last(2).count_by_status()', 'message': "Triggers if any host's clock goes out of sync with the time given by NTP. The offset threshold is configured in the Agent's `ntp.yaml` file.\n\nPlease read the [KB article](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/faq/network-time-protocol-ntp-offset-issues) on NTP Offset issues for more details on cause and resolution.", 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 19564752, 'multi': True, 'name': '[Auto] Clock in sync with NTP', 'created': '2020-06-23T12:27:30.374518+00:00', 'created_at': 1592915250000, 'creator': {'id': 1847513, 'handle': 'support-<ommitted>technologiesptyltd', 'name': 'Datadog Support', 'email': 'support-user-prod@datadoghq.com'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2020-06-23T12:27:30.374518+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-05T15:48:13+00:00', 'overall_state': 'No Data', 'type': 'service check', 'options': {'thresholds': {'warning': 1, 'ok': 1, 'critical': 1}, 'silenced': {}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>', 'probe_dc:aws:ap-southeast-2', 'probe_dc:aws:us-west-1', 'probe_dc:aws:eu-west-2', 'check_type:api', 'check_status:live'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'no_query', 'message': '<ommited>  the site is down <ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 24859757, 'multi': False, 'name': '[Synthetics] <ommitted> Website', 'created': '2020-10-28T05:22:53.747615+00:00', 'created_at': 1603862573000, 'creator': {'id': 2165425, 'handle': '<ommitted>', 'name': '<ommitted>', 'email': '<ommitted>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-01T00:40:37.638286+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-05T14:31:18+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'synthetics alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 20}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>', 'probe_dc:aws:ap-southeast-2', 'probe_dc:aws:us-west-1', 'probe_dc:aws:eu-west-2', 'check_type:api', 'check_status:live'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'no_query', 'message': '<ommited> <ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 25075092, 'multi': False, 'name': '[Synthetics] Broker Portal', 'created': '2020-11-02T12:49:25.906548+00:00', 'created_at': 1604321365000, 'creator': {'id': 2179074, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-01-21T03:07:18.678934+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2020-11-02T12:50:14+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'synthetics alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 20}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>', 'probe_dc:aws:ap-southeast-2', 'probe_dc:aws:us-west-1', 'probe_dc:aws:eu-west-2', 'check_type:api', 'check_status:live'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'no_query', 'message': '<ommited> <ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 25075173, 'multi': False, 'name': '[Synthetics] Consumer Portal', 'created': '2020-11-02T12:52:18.387320+00:00', 'created_at': 1604321538000, 'creator': {'id': 2179074, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-01-21T03:08:22.814234+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-01-08T23:34:34+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'synthetics alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 20}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>', 'probe_dc:aws:ap-southeast-2', 'probe_dc:aws:us-west-1', 'probe_dc:aws:eu-west-2', 'check_type:api', 'check_status:live'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'no_query', 'message': '<ommited> <ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 25075185, 'multi': False, 'name': '[Synthetics] Referrer Portal', 'created': '2020-11-02T12:54:04.573695+00:00', 'created_at': 1604321644000, 'creator': {'id': 2179074, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-01-21T03:09:44.559467+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-01-18T07:25:46+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'synthetics alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 20}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>', 'probe_dc:aws:us-west-1', 'probe_dc:aws:eu-west-2', 'check_type:api', 'check_status:live'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'no_query', 'message': '<ommited> <ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 25075205, 'multi': False, 'name': '[Synthetics] Admin Portal', 'created': '2020-11-02T12:55:01.827754+00:00', 'created_at': 1604321701000, 'creator': {'id': 2179074, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-01-28T05:27:04.581794+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-01-16T07:29:06+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'synthetics alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 20}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-broker-api/7847853bc84c4540} < 0', 'message': '<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 
'id': 25093054, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Broker Service API', 'created': '2020-11-02T19:14:14.213632+00:00', 'created_at': 1604344454000, 'creator': {'id': 2179074, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:32:27.211595+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2020-11-02T19:20:10+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>', 'probe_dc:aws:ap-southeast-1', 'check_type:browser', 'check_status:paused'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'no_query', 'message': '', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 25669789, 'multi': False, 'name': '[Synthetics] Smoke Test Suite 01', 'created': '2020-11-13T04:05:34.459038+00:00', 'created_at': 1605240334000, 'creator': {'id': 2190492, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-01-19T09:53:41.258475+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2020-12-22T14:59:51+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'synthetics alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 
'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>', 'probe_dc:aws:ap-southeast-1', 'check_type:browser', 'check_status:paused'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'no_query', 'message': '', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 26165829, 'multi': False, 'name': '[Synthetics] Smoke Test Suite 02', 'created': '2020-11-24T09:03:21.527745+00:00', 'created_at': 1606208601000, 'creator': {'id': 2190492, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-01-18T06:03:08.829387+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-01-18T04:08:10+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'synthetics alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['env:UAT', 'probe_dc:aws:ap-southeast-2', 'check_type:browser', 'check_status:paused'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'no_query', 'message': '', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 26872594, 'multi': False, 'name': '[Synthetics] UAT Smoke Test Suite 02 (cloned)', 'created': '2020-12-02T10:15:28.840851+00:00', 'created_at': 1606904128000, 'creator': {'id': 2190492, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-01-27T17:18:49.440416+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2020-12-10T23:51:35+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'synthetics alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'sum(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-m2m-service/c915c1e4d76ae6ad} < 1', 'message': '<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 27090558, 'multi': False, 'name': 'M2M API Monitor', 'created': '2020-12-07T13:33:48.518008+00:00', 'created_at': 1607348028000, 'creator': {'id': 2179074, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:31:15.037285+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2020-12-07T13:35:46+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'metric alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': False, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'evaluation_delay': 900, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': [], 'deleted': None, 'query': "events('priority:all sources:watchdog tags:story_category:infrastructure').by('story_type,story_key').rollup('count').last('30m') > 0", 'message': '<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 28413833, 'multi': True, 'name': '[Watchdog] Infrastructure Story detected', 'created': '2021-01-08T10:01:17.190296+00:00', 'created_at': 1610100077000, 'creator': {'id': 2165425, 'handle': '<ommitted>', 'name': '<ommitted>', 'email': '<ommitted>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-01-08T10:01:17.190296+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-01-27T10:28:23+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'event alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 
'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': False, 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0}, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': [], 'deleted': None, 'query': "events('priority:all sources:watchdog tags:story_type:aws_cloudfront,story_category:infrastructure').by('story_type,story_key').rollup('count').last('30m') > 0", 'message': '<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 28413856, 'multi': True, 'name': '[Watchdog] AWS Cloudfront Infrastructure Story detected', 'created': '2021-01-08T10:01:26.457103+00:00', 'created_at': 1610100086000, 'creator': {'id': 2165425, 'handle': '<ommitted>', 'name': '<ommitted>', 'email': '<ommitted>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-01-08T10:01:26.457103+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-01-27T10:27:48+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'event alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': False, 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0}, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>', 'probe_dc:aws:us-west-1', 'probe_dc:aws:eu-west-2', 'check_type:browser', 'check_status:live'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'no_query', 'message': '<ommited> <ommited> <ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 28502273, 'multi': False, 'name': '[Synthetics] Sanity check test suite', 'created': '2021-01-11T08:58:32.924362+00:00', 'created_at': 1610355512000, 'creator': {'id': 2190492, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T17:03:18.130974+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-01-30T07:44:54+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'synthetics alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>', 'probe_dc:aws:us-west-1', 'probe_dc:aws:eu-west-2', 'check_type:browser', 'check_status:paused'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'no_query', 'message': '', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29035835, 'multi': False, 'name': '[Synthetics] Smoke Suite for New Consumer Portal', 'created': '2021-01-21T06:43:47.010985+00:00', 'created_at': 1611211427000, 'creator': {'id': 2190492, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-01T07:42:31.705218+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-01T05:16:36+00:00', 'overall_state': 'Alert', 'type': 'synthetics alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-identity-server-api/731db6a21eba28f1} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29982839, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Identity Service - API', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:05:05.166784+00:00', 'created_at': 1612764305000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 
'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:32:01.847234+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:08:19+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-identity-server/5918a39a2b2894c7} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29982845, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Identity Service - Server', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:06:03.542475+00:00', 'created_at': 1612764363000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:31:44.668590+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:08:28+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': 
False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-identity-server-admin/8efe0b112ad20a64} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29983028, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Identity Service - Admin', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:09:21.979313+00:00', 'created_at': 1612764561000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:31:52.836731+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:18:11+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-broker-geodata-service/fb0e9c76ed83e8da} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29983060, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Infra - Geodata Service', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:10:22.878032+00:00', 'created_at': 1612764622000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:31:36.461983+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:17:43+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': 
{'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-message-service/1c7734cd7159acbe} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29983071, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Infra - Messaging Service', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:11:05.185221+00:00', 'created_at': 1612764665000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:31:24.273770+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:17:52+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-broker-text-bot-service/5390d04d89b711d5} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29983163, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Text-Bot Service', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:15:12.297508+00:00', 'created_at': 1612764912000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:31:03.838798+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:17:48+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-agent-connect/d4fb7eeecade1686} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29983169, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Agent Connect', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:16:13.289531+00:00', 'created_at': 1612764973000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:32:41.059302+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:18:39+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-broker-broker-connect/bf194b8f19346f4a} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29983177, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Broker Connect', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:16:50.948019+00:00', 'created_at': 1612765010000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:32:33.744675+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:18:47+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-broker-ac-middleware/66cfaac65be31bb8} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29983187, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Ac-Middleware', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:17:50.918888+00:00', 'created_at': 1612765070000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:32:48.083706+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:20:08+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': ['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/ecs-broker-document-service/153a3f9d1a5a387d} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29983197, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Document Service', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:18:35.287271+00:00', 'created_at': 1612765115000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:32:18.009116+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:27:58+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}, {'restricted_roles': None, 'tags': 
['<ommitted>'], 'deleted': None, 'query': 'avg(last_15m):<ommitted>{<ommitted>/document-service-prod/537e7184dd3462c5} < 0', 'message': '<ommited> \n@<ommited>', 'matching_downtimes': [], 'id': 29983210, 'multi': False, 'name': 'Document Service - PROD', 'created': '2021-02-08T06:19:48.364977+00:00', 'created_at': 1612765188000, 'creator': {'id': 2289540, 'handle': '<ommited>', 'name': None, 'email': '<ommited>'}, 'org_id': 430079, 'modified': '2021-02-08T06:32:09.952701+00:00', 'priority': None, 'overall_state_modified': '2021-02-08T06:28:10+00:00', 'overall_state': 'OK', 'type': 'query alert', 'options': {'notify_audit': False, 'locked': False, 'timeout_h': 0, 'silenced': {}, 'include_tags': True, 'no_data_timeframe': None, 'require_full_window': True, 'new_host_delay': 300, 'notify_no_data': False, 'renotify_interval': 0, 'escalation_message': '', 'thresholds': {'critical': 0.0, 'critical_recovery': 1.0}}}]
```

I have omitted some values for security reasons

Comment: can you mention your JSON response as well

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

I have used a dummy API to show. you can replace it with your API and do necessary change.

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then((res) => {
      this.setState({
        status: res.data
      });
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { status } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {status && status.map((sta) => (
            <div
              key={sta.id}
              className="card text-white bg-info mb-3"
              style={{ maxWidth: "15rem" }}
            >
              <div className="card-header">{sta.id}</div>
              <div className="card-body">
                <h5 className="card-title">Info card title</h5>
                <p className="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up
                  the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

CSS

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.card {
  margin: 1px;
}
```

[Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/bootstrap-4-react-hello-world-import-forked-yu57c?file=/src/styles.css)